# JFreeChart: Logarithmic Axis Tick Labels missing

Tags: jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to make XYLineCharts with a Logarithmic y-axis but am facing an issue that I am unable to resolve.

My x, y values are very low in some cases (in one such case, the y-axis values for the dataset range between 4.5e-8 to 1.7). I plot these values on a XYLineChart using a Logarithmic Axis for the y-axis (and using LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH) and .setExpTickLabelsFlag(true) on the y-axis to create the exponential tick units). I set my range's bounds from 4.5e-8 to 1.7 and can see the points plotted clearly but there are no tick labels visible for the y-axis !

I was earlier having this issue while zooming into the charts but I have fixed the zoom & AutoZoom by over-riding those methods. 
My current LogarithmicAxis works well for most of my x, y datasets but in a few cases, the y-axis is plotted but does not show any Tick Labels on it, despite my creating them & setting their visibility to true.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this & ensure that the Tick Labels are visible no matter what the y-axis values may be, please let me know soon as I need to get this done ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
Does anyone have any input/ idea about how to ensure that Tick Labels for the range (y) axis are always visible on the Chart ? I am using LogarithmicAxis instead of LogAxis as I want numbers in the following format: 1e-10, 1e-8, ... , 1e0, 1e1 & so on.

However, LogarithmicAxis does not work for very small dataset ranges such as if the LowerBound= 0.0 & upperBound= 2.07E-6; in this case, the y-axis does not show any tick labels. 

Kindly help me out with this. 
Thanks.

Comment: I can't find a class that implements both `createLogTickUnits` and `setExpTickLabelsFlag` so you may be mixing implementations of `Axis` nevertheless I have tried both `LogarithmicAxis` and `LogAxis` and both generated tick marks you will need to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct , Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @GrahamA : Hi Graham, thanks for the reply. I was earlier using: `final LogarithmicAxis logAxis= new LogarithmicAxis("logAxis");` and `logAxis.setStandardTickUnits(LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH));` to have values with scientific notation ('e') on the y-axis. I changed the second line of code to
 `logAxis.setStandardTickUnits(LogarithmicAxis.createStandardTickUnits());`
However, for a dataset where min. Range (i.e., RangeAxis lowerBound)= -2.608E-7 and max Range= 2.074E-6, the plotted chart still has the Tick Labels missing on the y-axis.

Comment: I tried to manually set the lowerBound to `0.0` with upperBound value= 2.074E-6 but even then the tick labels were missing. It then seemed to be as if this Range: `0.0 to 2.074E-6` is too small for the tick labels to be displayed. I then changed my code so that if the lowerBound < 0, then the lowerBound value should be the 1st dataset value > 0. In this case, it was 1E-7. The new Range then set was from `1E-7 to 2.074E-6` & this displays all the tick labels ! It works for now but I do not understand why the error originally occurred.